# Consulta de CNPJ utilizando PHP

Tags: php, html, libcurl

**A situação** é a seguinte, tenho um script em PHP que faz consultas de CNPJ pelo site da Receita Federal, porém ele está me retornando alguns erros, *na verdade não sei se são erros.*

### **Código HTML/PHP**

`consulta.html`

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>CNPJ e Captcha</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="processa.php">
            <p><span class="titleCats">CNPJ e Captcha</span>
              <br />
              <input type="text" name="CNPJ" maxlength="19" required /> 
              <b style="color: red">CNPJ</b>
              <br />
              <img src="getcaptcha.php" border="0">
              <br />
              <input type="text" name="CAPTCHA" maxlength="6" required />
              <b style="color: red">O que vê na imagem acima?</b>
              <br />
            </p>
            <p>
              <input id="id_submit" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Consultar"/>
            </p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`processa.php`

```
    <?php

    require('funcoes.php');

    $cnpj = $_POST['CNPJ'];
    $captcha = $_POST['CAPTCHA'];

    // pega html resposta da receita
    $getHtmlCNPJ = getHtmlCNPJ($cnpj, $captcha);

    if($getHtmlCNPJ)
    {
    // volova os dados em um array
    $campos = parseHtmlCNPJ($getHtmlCNPJ);
    var_dump($campos);
    }
    ?>
```

`funcoes.php`

Como o código do `funcoes.php` é muito grande e iria desconfigurar a pergunta por deixa-la extensa demais, vou deixar o link com o código inteiro, para ver é só clicar [aqui](http://barietoner.com.br/js/code.html)

### **Agora o resultado:**

```
  array(23) {
     [0]=> string(18) "17.81X.03X/0X01-XX"
     [1]=> string(10) "13/03/2013"
     [2]=> string(58) "XXXXXXX - EMPRESA - ME"
     [3]=> string(10) "TONER XXXXX"
     [4]=> string(90) "X7.X1-X-01 - Comércio varejista especializado 
  de XXX"
     [5]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(67) "47.X1-X-02 - 
  Recarga de XXX para equipamentos de XXXXX "
        [1]=> string(80) 
  "95.11-8-00 -Reparação e XXX de XX e de XXXXX XX"
     }
     [6]=> string(68) "230-5 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXX (DE NATUREZA EMPRESARIA)" 
     [7]=> string(37) "R GERONIMO DOS SANTOS (JD W XX)"
     [8]=> string(2) "55"
     [9]=> string(0) ""
     [10]=> string(10) "09.X70-XXX"
     [11]=> string(15) "NOVA XXXX"
     [12]=> string(21) "SAO XXXXXX XXXX"
     [13]=> string(2) "SP"
     [14]=> string(26) "assessoriaprisma@XXX"
     [15]=> string(14) "(11) 4X5-3XX08" 
     [16]=> string(5) "*****"
     [17]=> string(5) "ATIVA"
     [18]=> string(10) "13/03/2XXX"
     [19]=> string(0) ""
     [20]=> string(8) "********"
     [21]=> string(8) "********" 
     ["status"]=> string(2) "OK"
 }
```

Não sei se estou certo, mas o resultado deveria ser retornado da mesma forma que é retornado na receita federal.
Desculpem minha ignorância no assunto e na linguagem PHP, mas caso esse script não esteja com nada errado, como posso fazer para formatar esse resultado?

Alias, para quem quiser ver ao vivo, [tente você mesmo](http://barietoner.com.br/cep/cnpj.php)

### **O que pretende?**

Preciso que o resultado retorne formatado. **Como assim?** Por exemplo, uma linha indicando CNPJ {cnpj} outra linha indicando RAZÃO SOCIAL {razão social}.
Isso é só um exemplo, resumindo, preciso formatar o resultado para o entendimento do mesmo.

> *Obs: Sei que perguntas feitas a base de links podem e provavelmente vão receber downvotes, mas quero deixar claro que minha intenção é
>   boa, já que também estou disponibilizando um script muito bom de
>   consultas de cnpj funcional e não pretendo remover o link, a não ser
>   que seja removido por algum terceiro*

Comment: Qual é o problema? quais são so erros?

Comment: O "erro" está no resultado, editei a pergunta com o que pretendo. @rray, não sei com certeza, se isso é exatamente um erro ou é o resultado correto, mas o que preciso é que o resultado esteja formato, ou pelo menos, um guia para que eu mesmo formate. Deu pra entender?

Comment: `echo $campos[0] .' - '. $campos[4];` isso?

Comment: Sim isso, a parte do `array(23) { [0]=> string(18) "17.81X.03X/0X01-XX"`

Comment: isso ai o resultado do var_dump para pegar os valores individualmente vc precisa fazer isso manualmente como coloquei no comentário anterior.

Comment: desculpe @rray mas, como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: vc precisa colocar o indice(número) desejado na variável `campos` por exemplo o 1 parecer o cnpj o 2 o tipo de empresa e o 3 o nome, para exibi-los primeiro remova o `var_dump($campos)` e coloque `echo $campos[0] .' # '. $campos[2] . ' # '. $campos[3];`

Comment: Para ficar mais fácil de ler essa informação no futuro, use isso: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($campos);`

Comment: Amigo, se não for demais, poderia me ajudar pela forma de resposta? Iria ajudar demais e acredito que outras pessoas poderão ter o mesmo problema que eu e com sua ajuda iria solucionar os delas também

Comment: Era esse o problema? posso responder sim

Comment: Era isso @rray, só estou precisando que os resultados apareçam de forma que dê pra entender corretamente e pra que eu possa incluir em um layout depois. Agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é nenhum erro isso é apenas a saída do `var_dump($campos)`, para manipular ou exibir as informações individualmente é necessário informar o índice desejado.

```
echo 'CNPJ: '. $campos[0] . ' Nome da empresa: '. $campos[3];
```

Comment: No fim era bem simples, obrigado @rray te agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: E quando muda a array, como eu posso fazer para selecionar outra array ? Por exemplo: `[5]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(67) "47.X1-X-02 -   Recarga de XXX para equipamentos de XXXXX " [1]=> string(80) `

Comment: No caso, a array fica no valor (2) como faço pra selecionar ela pra conseguir puxar o $campos[0] da array 2?

Comment: @VictorGomes vc precisa fazer `echo $campos[5][0]` pq existe um array dentro da índice 5. qualquer coisa avisa ai

Comment: Retornou o valor: Array[0], não deu certo

Comment: pode conferir [Aqui](http://barietoner.com.br/cep/cnpj.php) os resultados, eu ainda to arrumando algumas coisas, tentei fazer o mais próximo da própria receita federal, mas enfim, acho que é melhor pra você ver testando

Comment: @VictorGomes faz assim e mostra o resultado, `echo '<pre>' print_r($campos[5]);`

Comment: `'' print_r(Array)` agora retornou esse erro

Comment: @VictorGomes depois vou dar uma olhada no exemplo.

Comment: certo, agradeço @rray

Comment: to quebrando a cabeça e não to conseguindo, desculpe a ignorância no assunto, mas ta complicado haha

Comment: @VictorGomes não consigo acessar daqui o link, pelo código da pergunta o certo é `echo $campos[5][0]` ou `echo $campos[5][0]` pq dentro da chave `5` tem outro array, ai vc acessa a chave `0` ou `1` .

Comment: é então acho que vou ficar travado nessa parte, vou dar uma estudada e tomara que eu consiga resolver isso em breve, pois basicamente só falta isso, obg @rray agradeço a paciência

Answer (score 2):

O resultado está aparecendo assim pois você está utilizando o "*var_dump*". Esta função mostrará uma representação estruturada sobre uma ou mais expressões, incluindo o tipo e o valor. No seu caso seu array parece normal, mas para mostrá-lo da forma que você quer você pode utilizar ou por meio de "*print_r*" ou por meio do "*echo*", assim:

```
// indicando sempre o índice do dado que deseja
print_r($campos[0]);
echo $campos[0];
```

Se utilizar o "*print_r*" você pode colocar sem o índice, mas isso mostraria o array inteiro.

```
//assim mostra todo array e suas chaves.
print_r($campos);
```

Para mostrar linha a linha do array você poderia montar um laço utilizando por exemplo o o laço for:

```
$campos = array('0' => "Pimeiro", '2' => "Segundo", '3' => "Terceiro" );
$itens = count($campos);

for ($i=0; $i <= $itens; $i++) { 
    echo ($campos[$i]."<br>");
}
```

No exemplo acima utilizo o "*count()*" para saber quantos itens possui o array para poder fazer o for.

Bem acho que é isso

Att;

Comment: Bem explicado, deu pra entender que não era erro no código e sim erro meu haha, agradeço @Fleuquer-lima

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar, qualquer coisa estou a disposição!

Comment: no caso das partes da ARRAY, como eu posso faze para seliciona-las ? Por exemplo pra selecionar a string é $campos[4] e pra selecionar o campo 0 da array 2 ?

Comment: Por exemplo, em um dos exemplos que vc postou um dos índices só seu array é: "X7.X1-X-01 - Comércio varejista especializado  de XXX". Isto é por exemplo o "$campo[3]". E tudo isso é uma String (texto basicamente), se você quer que ele retorne somente a palavra "Comércio" por exemplo, você teria que quebrar a string ou para outro array ou para uma posição dentro da string. Mas só funcionária para todos os seus casos se as posições das quebrar forem iguais ou marcadas por um "espaço" ou um caractere especial tipo "/".

Comment: Consegui resolver, muito obrigado meu amigo, valeu mesmo